# Use maps to pinpoint other users of the app?

Tags: android, gps, maps, location

I cant seem to find anything googling regarding this, i essentially want to use the Google maps API, and have it annotate the other people using this app?

I've already implemented maps using polaris and can add markers however, im at an odds at how this would be achieved?

Comment: You may want to break this question down into several smaller, more specific ones. This one deals with using the location services and web services. You'll get better answers if you can ask about concrete problems rather than conceptual ones.

Comment: Thats the thing, though i have no idea WHAT to ask, thats the problem, even so far as knowing what to research